# How to check if button is clicked in onclick method in IQ test

Tags: android, onclick

I want to write an IQ test app.
I used 3 radio buttons for the answers and a button for the next question.
Now I want to use a button instead of a radiobutton. 
I dont know what to do in the onclick() method.
Please help me :)

This is my code:

```
public void onclick(View view_obj) {

    if (!radiobt_obj1.isChecked() && !radiobt_obj2.isChecked()
            && !radiobt_obj3.isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        estimation();

        if (btn1.getText().toString().equals("Next")) {
            if (!cursor_obj.isAfterLast()) {
                number++;




                txt_obj.setText(cursor_obj.getString(cursor_obj
                        .getColumnIndex("question")));
                radiobt_obj1.setText(cursor_obj.getString(cursor_obj
                        .getColumnIndex("ans1")));
                radiobt_obj2.setText(cursor_obj.getString(cursor_obj
                        .getColumnIndex("ans2")));
                radiobt_obj3.setText(cursor_obj.getString(cursor_obj
                        .getColumnIndex("ans3")));


                set_invis();

                cursor_obj.moveToNext();

                checked_buttons();

                if (!cursor_obj.isAfterLast() && number <40) {
                    btn1.setText("Next");

                } else {
                    btn1.setText("Result");
                    cursor_obj.close();
                    db.close();
                }
            }
        } else {
            Intent intent_obj = new Intent(AnxietyQuestion.this,AnxietyResult.class);
            intent_obj.putExtra("value", result);
            startActivity(intent_obj);
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

public void estimation() {

```
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            if (radiobt_obj1.isChecked()) {
                result += 2;
            }
            if (radiobt_obj2.isChecked()) {
                result += 0;
            }
            if (radiobt_obj3.isChecked()) {
                result += 1;
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

in xml:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="onClickNext"
/>
```

in Java

```
(...)
public void onClickNext(View v){
    (...)
}
```

Also you can attach different `onClick`-listeners on every `View` you desire, but try first to work via XML to get an idea of it. But don't use just one single `onClick` method, it will make you crazy.